# python multiplying python float with numpy float

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm trying to do the following:
`self.cashflows["Balance"] * self.assumptions["Default Rates"][current_period - 1]`
where cashflows is a list with python floats and assumptions is a list with numpy floats.
I used numpy to fill the assumption vector and I am getting the following error when I try to multiply the two:
`can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64`
I get the error but what would be my best course of action here?
thx

Comment: Is the left side of that multiplication a numpy array or an ordinary list or tuple?  Python doesn't support multiplication of a list by a numpy.float64.  You'll need to convert the list into a numpy array.

Comment: @FrankYellin. Seems like a list. Result would be a bit unexpected if this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. Do you want to multiply every item in the list `self.cashflow["Balance"]` with `self.assumptions["Default Rates"][current_period - 1]`? Then you can use some list comprehension:

`result = [q * self.assumptions["Default Rates"][current_period - 1] for q in self.cashflow["Balance"]]`

or convert your second argument to `np.float`:

`result = self.assumptions["Default Rates"][current_period - 1]* np.asarray(self.cashflow["Balance"])`

Otherwise, multiplying a whole list by N repeats that list N times. If thats what you want, cast your `np.float64` to `int`.

EDIT: Added missing multiplication sign

Comment: For the last part, use the `item` method

Comment: Thanks - I was just targeting one element!